# What is this syntax? Only function expressions are arguments wrapped in parentheses

Tags: solidity

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) {
    (_from);
    (_value);
    (_data);
 }
```

From https://etherscan.io/address/0xd1dd82d1ded8f40c200b89455050e9c18d918504#code.

Comment: They do nothing, it is only to silence the warning from solidity linter that some arguments are not used.

Comment: Ah thank you! If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does nothing. It is only used to silence the warning from solidity linter that some arguments are not used.

The compiler should smart enough to not generate any code.